# CSS/SASS dropdown menu issue

Tags: css, sass

Im stuck on a problem, I have re created the twitter nav and now want a dropdown menu to appear when I hover on the 'settings' text, however, I dont know a way around this as I have added overflow: hidden to the nav. I also want it to stay fixed under the settings text but I cant find a way around this. Check out the pen.

HTML

```
<nav class="userNav">
   <div class="navCenter">
      <ul class="rightUL navRight">
         <li><a href="#">settings</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

SASS

```
.navRight
    float: right

// Main signed in nav that user can see when they log in

.userNav
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    left: 0
    width: 100%
    height: 60px

    background-color: white
    overflow: hidden

    .navCenter
        max-width: 1280px
        margin: 0 auto

        .rightUL
            display: inline-block
            padding: 12.5px 0 0 0 

            li
                display: inline-block
                padding-right: 10px

                a
                    color: #5A5A5A
                    text-decoration: none
                    vertical-align: -5px

                    &:hover, &.active
                        color: #21AAEA
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/joshgallagher24/pen/EaEZoZ)

Comment: Not to mean any offence, but its nearly impossible to track your css at this moment, you need to add your brackets {}

Comment: @Philip [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) doesn't have brackets, only indentation. (The alternative syntax SCSS uses brackets though)

Comment: @Philip Look at the codepens compiled sass

Comment: This is why I prefer SCSS over plain SASS: readability. (But everyone gets their cup of tea or coffee as they please.) On topic: I can't seem to be able to find your drop down menu that you are trying to toggle. Where is it in HTML? Also, I think that most people will automatically "click" settings to get to settings anyway, so with a JS-basied click event it is quite easy to absolutely position the desired drop-down.

Comment: I think part of the problem you are having is the amount of nesting. SASS is great because it does allow nesting, but you shouldn't really go more than three levels, including pseudo elements. It improves readability.

As for your question, there is no way around the overflow hidden. You should absolutely position the dropdowns and hide them using `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @BramVanroy yes I was going to use jquery to toggle it, however, when I position it absolutely, when the browser resizes it doesnt stay under the settings text it disappears ?

Comment: Add `position: relative` to it's parent.

Comment: If this is a pure CSS problem, **only post the CSS**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove ov: hid from nav and add it to leftUL.
And then add a dropdown in settings ~ li in pos:absolute . I have added a dommy dropdown for you , you can add styles for it and if you need any help then you can ask me.

here is the code .

HTML

```
<nav class="userNav">
                <div class="navCenter">
                    <ul class="leftUL navLeft">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li
                        ><li><a href="#"><i class="icon-globe"></i> <span>Notifications</span></a></li
                        ><li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> <span>Messages</span></a></li
                        ><li><a href="#" class="active"><i class="icon-user"></i> <span>Me</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="navCenter">
                    <ul class="rightUL navRight">
                        <li class="search">
                            <form>
                                <input type="search" placeholder="Search Meeu">
                                <i class="icon-search"></i>
                            </form>
                        </li>
<li class="has-drop">            
                          <a href="#">settings</a>
                            <div class="drop">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
        </ul>
 </li>
                        </div>  
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

SASS

```
 =placeholder 
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder
    @content

  &:-moz-placeholder
    @content

  &::-moz-placeholder
    @content

  &:-ms-input-placeholder
    @content
body
  font-family: sans-serif

.navLeft
  float: left

.navRight
  float: right

// Main signed in nav that user can see when they log in

.userNav
  position: fixed
  top: 0
  left: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 68px

  background-color: white

  +single-box-shadow(0, 0px, 1px, 1.5px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1))

  .navCenter
    max-width: 1280px
    margin: 0 auto

    .leftUL
      display: inline-block
      padding: 18px 0 0 0
      overflow: hidden

      li
        display: inline-block

        a
          padding: 30px 12px 15px 12px

          border-bottom: 4px solid #5A5A5A
          color: #5A5A5A
          text-decoration: none

          +single-transition(all, .15s, ease-in-out)

          &:hover, &.active
            padding-bottom: 11px

            border-color: #21AAEA
            color: #21AAEA

          i
            font-size: 24px

          span
            font-size: 14px
            vertical-align: 4px

    .rightUL
      display: inline-block
      padding: 12.5px 0 0 0 
      .has-drop
        position: relative
        &:hover
          .drop
            display: block

      .drop
        display: none
        position: absolute
        top: 100%
        right: 0
        width: 150px
        background: blue
        padding: 20px
        border-radius: 10px
        li
          display: block
        a
          color: #fff

      .search
        display: inline-block

        form

          i
            position: relative
            left: -32px

            color: #292f33
            font-size: 14px

          input
            width: 200px
            height: 35px
            padding: 0 35px 0 10px

            border: 1px solid #e1e8ed
            outline: none
            font-size: 12px
            line-height: 1
            background-color: #f5f8fa

            @include placeholder
              padding: 2.5px 0 0 0 
              color: #292f33

            +border-radius(21px)
            +single-transition(background-color, .15s, ease-in-out)

            &:focus
              background-color: transparent

              @include placeholder
                color: #8899A6

      li
        display: inline-block
        padding-right: 10px

        a
          color: #5A5A5A
          text-decoration: none
          font-size: 14px

          +single-transition(all, .15s, ease-in-out)

          &:hover, &.active
            color: #21AAEA
```

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYVJqy)

Comment: Thankyou, I'm going to add a click event instead though !